# Access fields in an array contained in a model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have some JavaScript code that needs to be able to access fields of an array of objects that is contained within my model. I currently have this:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
for(var i = 0; i < model.testobject.length; i++) {
    console.log(model.testobject[i]);
}
```

Which prints out the fields within each object of `testobject`. But say I have a field, `ID`, in my `testobject` class. How do I then access that? Doing this:

```
console.log(model.testobject[i].ID);
```

Does not work. Do I have to somehow encode that specific instance of `testobject` before accessing it's fields?

And yes, before anyone says it I know this should be contained within the controller. As it currently stands though, that's not possible for this project.

This is the general structure of what is printed out:

```
Object {field: value}
```

Edit:
I attempted to use `JSON.stringify` on my `model.IdentifiApprovalConfigurations` and it seems I got a little close to reaching my solution. This is what it looks like now:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(model.testobject[i]).ID);
```

However, this prints out `undefined`.

Edit 2:
Oops, seems the `ID` field I'm trying to access isn't being populated before I send them to my view which is my own issue. `JSON.stringify` works though, and I understand why it wasn't working earlier.

Final edit:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model.testobject[i])).Value
```

I had to stringify and then parse my JSON to access the value.

Comment: Can you show the results of logging `model.testobject[i]`?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Unfortunately I cannot show the actual data, but I'll edit my post with an example of what it looks like.

Comment: That's fine. I'm more concerned with structure, you can redact the actual values.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I updated my post with the general layout.

Comment: In order to work you JSON has to have the following format `{
    "testobject":
    [
        {
            ID:"1"
        },
        {
            ID:"2"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: That's not really "closer". All you did was call `ID` off of a string. A JavaScript string has no `ID` member, so you get `undefined`. That tells you nothing really.

Comment: @AlexArt. Yeah I just realized... I'm still fairly new to web development in general so mistakes like these are pretty common for me unfortunately :( Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @ChrisPratt I just found that out. I'm figuring out how to access fields in a JSON object now.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm still starting out with web development, I forgot that I needed to convert my `object` into a `JSON` object. This:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model.testobject[i])).Value
```

Is the final piece of code that allows me to `stringify` an object, `parse` the `JSON` and then access fields within that object.

Comment: Wow. Definitely shouldn't need to do that... What are you trying to do?

Comment: @timothyclifford Access field which is in an object in an array contained in my `Model` which I pulled down and encoded. This has to be done because I have a `DropDownList` which, when I select an option I have to populate a couple of elements on my page according to what was selected. I can't refresh the page however, so I can't use my controller to help with this.